# How long do IBM-Graph authorization tokens last for?

Tags: ibm-graph

In IBM-Graph, in order to avoid excessively long authorization for each request we request a session token first, and send that along in the headers of any subsequent requests.  Exactly as explained in the documentation.

In order to persist this single token across our applications cluster, we are currently storing the active IBM-Graph session token in memcached.  This way each node of our cluster pulls this token out prior to every request to our graph.

Having monitored this key, it appears to not have changed/expired since we made our first request a couple of days ago.  Therefore, I have some questions regarding it:

- How long do these session tokens last for?
- Is our current method of distributing this single key even required?
- Is there a better method?

It would be nice to be able to remove the need to hit memcached for every request altogether. Knowing how long they last for could help us to devise a more elegant solution than constantly hammering a single small memcached instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How long do these session tokens last for?

IBM Graph tokens are intended to last for a long while - you should expect somewhere around a day, though it's subject to change. It shouldn't ever be shorter than an hour.

> Is our current method of distributing this single key even required?

No, not really. I'd write some code to automatically acquire new tokens on HTTP 403 (i.e., at boot time and when they expire) and use them locally. There's no limit to the number of tokens you can have active at one time.